# Centering an image within a div

Tags: html, css

I have already set the border of an image within a `div` to be none.  I now want to center that image within its containing div.  I have tried using the `margin: 0 auto;` but that did not work.

I am sure I am overlooking something stupid but I would like to enlist the help of the stackoverflow community so this doesn't take me an hour of staring at the screen to figure out.  Thanks a lot.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="banner">

            <img src="logo3.png"/>
            <!--<img src="kslf_logo.png"/>
            <img src="logo2.png" title="Katie Samson Lacrosse Festival Logo"/>-->


            <div id="social_network">
                <a href="#" target="_blank" title="Check out the Facebook Page!">Facebook</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS...

```
#banner {
    height: 100px;
    width: 960px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#banner img {
    border: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try setting the image’s `display` property to `block`:

```
banner {
    height: 100px;
    width: 960px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

banner img {
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Applying `text-align: center` to your banner div will center its inline and inline-block children (which encompasses the img tag).

The reason why your code wasn't working is because `margin: 0 auto` will only center block elements.

Answer (score 0):

horizontal: just try

```
text-align:center;
```

:)

Comment: For some reason I have not gotten the hang of posting HTML in here without it rending it as a page, sorry about that, but I think this solution only works in IE,and its not working in this case anyways, is there a cross browser compliant way to do it?

Comment: @Dan: fixed it. You have to intend every code by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
banner {
     height:100px;
     text-align:center;
     width:960px;
     padding-bottom:10px;}
```

or if the img is of specific size then

```
banner img {
         display:block;
         width: <somevalue>px;
         border:none;
         margin:0 auto;
         }
```

will work ..

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just `margin: auto;`. No zero needed.

Answer (score 0):

After many exhaustive tries to center align an image in a div (vertically and/or horizontally), I understood the following.
To vertically center align an image in a div.

```
.div {
 display:flex;
justify-content:center
}
```

To horizontally center align an image in a div.

```
.div {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

To center both vertically and horizontally an image in a div, there are 2 options
(1)

```
div {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

(2)

```
.div {
display:flex
}

.div > img {
margin: auto
}
```