# Centering images inside divs

Tags: html, css

I have a footer with nine links.. I simulated my problem with this two links:

I need to center (vertical and horizontal) all classes *treeText*.

Each *treeText* is an image with some text drawed. It should stay in the middle of the *tree*.

---

I have this html:

```
<footer>
    <div class="grove">
        <div class="link">
            <img class="tree" />
            <img class="treeText" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxqQu.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <img class="tree" />
            <img class="treeText" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zROOo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

---

and this css:

```
footer, div, img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
footer {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px dotted #000;
}
.grove {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
} 
.link {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
img.tree {
    content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imj11.png');
}
img.treeText {
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}
```

---

[Live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/615n5q1o/2/)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134333/centering-an-image-within-a-div

Comment: Why the down vote? Other then the question being one that has been asked a few times very well structured question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
footer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
}
.grove {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
} 
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
img.tree {
  content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imj11.png');
}

img.treeText {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto; 
}
```

Comment: So, the trick here was set _top_, _bottom_, _left_ and _right_ to _zero_ in the class _treeText_, right? That's nice! Thank you!