# centering a image in a section

Tags: css, web, sass, pug

I want this image be right in the center of the page, in a section but it is not working, btw I'am using jade and sass. 
Jade:

```
section.believe(data-section-name='texture', <='', body='')
      img.minion(src="/images/IMG_6219.jpg")
```

Sass:

```
  .minion
    top: 50%
    left: 50%
    padding: 100px
    margin: 0 auto
    height: 10%
    transform: rotate(90deg)
```

[This is what keeps happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTQpL.jpg)

Comment: I would encourage you to use a div instead of a section tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134333/centering-an-image-within-a-div

Comment: You can give `display: inline-block` to the child and `text-align: center` to the parent.  Else you should make sure that your section has `display: block` and that it is taking up the full width of the page.

Comment: the reason i used the section tag was to use scroll snapping with scrollify (http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/) it just make it easier to organize.

Comment: - Jordan Mulder I tried that but it did not change anything.               .believe
  text-align: center
  display: block

.minion
  display: inline-block
  top: 50%
  left: 50%
  display: block
  padding: 100px
  height: 10%
  transform: rotate(90deg)

Comment: you are likely missing `position: absolute`  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrXqEV

Comment: Still not centered, it is off center to the right

Comment: I might be misinterpreting, but perhaps try:
`.believe {display:block;} .minion {display:block;margin:0 auto;}`

Edit: Sorry I pressed enter while trying to figure out how to add the code snippet style :)

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS or Jade->HTML compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS/HTML**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.minion
    position: absolute
    top: calc(50% - 400px)
    left: calc(50% - 400px)
    margin: 0
```

400px = half of the image width/height