# CSS center any image in div

Tags: html, css, image, center

Lets say I have `div` with `width: 300px` and `height: 200px`
I want any image inside this `div` to be centered both horizontally and vertically no matter if image is bigger or smaller than `div`;

For smaller images `margin: 0 auto` works well but higher image protrude to the right and isn't centered.

For bigger images this works:

```
height: 100%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

I couldn't find any combination of those and didn't find any solution how to perfectly center this image.

Comment: But you still want to scroll to see the entire picture or just "crop" the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering an image within a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134333/centering-an-image-within-a-div)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position: absolute` to `img` and `position: relative` to `div`

```css
.el {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 50px 150px;
}
img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000000/ffffff">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}
```

Comment: ...but just be aware of browser compatibility issues

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Well that **may** work but compatibility says bye bye.