# Center div in middle of backround image across all screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

I am using this code to display a background image that takes the full vertical height of the browser.

```
<div id="outer"></div>
```

CSS

```
#outer {
  background-image: url(https://www.mydomain./image.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I am looking to place a div inside, which is both vertically and horizontally centered in the middle of the image for all screen resolutions.

So far I have been unsuccessful with everything I tried. This needs to be supported by majority of browsers.

Comment: Please show us your attempts.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485593/css-center-any-image-in-div/37485686#37485686

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `height` and `width` for the inner `div`, then use `margin: auto` to center it horizontally, and `padding: calc(50vh - 10px) 0` to center vertically. The `10px` must be half of the height of your inner `div`. Try this:

```css
#outer {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x100');
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#inner {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: calc(50vh - 10px) 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most noteworthy solution. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Position Absolute and the translate -50% method**

```css
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.outer {
  position: relative;
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/55PnNyJ.jpg);
  height:100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.4);
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="centered">I'm (almost) On A Boat</div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/j7rgjspt/2/

---

**Option 2: Flexbox and justify-content/align-items center**

```css
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/55PnNyJ.jpg);
  height:100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.centered {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.4);
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="centered">I'm (almost) On A Boat</div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/j7rgjspt/1/